# Securely Ship Names

Tags: ios, security, encryption

I want to deploy an iPhone app with names of things as part of the deployed app. The user will see the names after they log in successfully (using a standard existing login service that already exists.). However, I don't want the names accessible by someone who can decrypt the app. In other words, they could decrypt the app and get the strings. See [Finding constants from a decrypted iOS app executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122493/finding-constants-from-a-decrypted-ios-app-executable) and [Reverse Engineering Tools](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Reverse_Engineering_Tools)

How can I ship the names encrypted and then have the app decrypt it after they log in? It seems to me that whatever decrypting code I write/use would also be available to the person decrypting the app.

It'd be **very nice** if I didn't have to create a custom server solution just to send the app names once they are logged in. However, it may come to that.

Our top security person is going to be hitting this app hard. So, it has to be airtight security. So the answer in ["Best way to securely ship static text inside a iOS app?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543463/best-way-to-securely-ship-static-text-inside-a-ios-app) won't work.

Ideas?

**Update**: Can we pre-populate the keystore in iPhone and Android somehow with the secure information such that it cannot be hacked?

Comment: Ask your "top security person" for help.

Comment: @zaph I understand why you might say that. :) I wanted a second / developer opinion since I have already had conversations with the security person and they did not catch this.

Comment: Find a new "top" guy then. He shouldn't be replaceable by Internet strangers.

Comment: Understand that it is impossible to 100% protect something from the user. The concept is to increase the work factor of the attacker beyond the abilities or willingness to expend the time/energy for the value obtained from a successful attack. Because of this you must define the attacker you are defending against ranging from a curious teenager to a nation state and the value of the data being protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypt the items prior to inclusion in the app and do not include the encryption key in the app. Instead pass the key to the app after the user correctly logs in.

Simply use AES encryption correctly, that will secure the data.

It is not important that the decryption method be secret, only that the decryption key be secret.

Comment: Thanks @zaph. The decryption key would come from the server. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the most secure method. Also on iOS embedding the key in the app is not out of the question, the binary can only be decrypted by jailbreaking, installing tools so the code can be examined when loaded to run.